# Remote procedure call failed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2015

Operating System        : Windows 8

Visual Studio installed : 2015 Enterprise Edition

Installed successfully : SQL Server 2008 R2

Installed successfully : SQL server management studio

But while checking the services through SQL configuration manager cannot see the instance server :

> "remote procedure call failed"

Comment: please comment on down votes

Comment: Go to directory where you installed SQL Server and see if there is installed files for instance. If you not change the path, then default path is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\`. At this point you can see many folder among which can be yours.

Comment: let me check then..thanks @veljasije

Comment: yes i can see but it doesnt show in configuration manager

Comment: Do you have another version of SQL Server installed? Every version has own Configuration Manager, so you muste be sure too look into right version of SSCM

Comment: no i have sql server 2008 r2 and i can see that through command prompt

Comment: Can you connect to the instance using SSMS? Are you tried to call procedure from SSMS? What is output? Try to run SSCM as `Run as Administrator`. Are you ever installed some other versions of SQL Server on this machine?

Comment: yes i can open in ssms even without admin privilege

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79487/discussion-between-veljasije-and-utility).

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have more than once instance of SQL installed, I've seen it happen where Express has also been installed on the server.

Browse directly to the correct version of configuration manager here:

- SQL Server 2016  - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager13.msc
- SQL Server 2014  - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc
- SQL Server 2012  - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc
- SQL Server 2008  - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager10.msc